# When/How to sort Realm child <List> properties for UITableView in Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, realm

I am using 2 Realm objects for the data source in my UITableView:

```
class SectionDate: Object {

   @objc dynamic var date = Date()
   let rowDates = List<RowDate>() 
}
class RowDate: Object {

   @objc dynamic var dateAndTime = Date()
}
tableViewData = realm.objects(SectionDate.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "date", ascending: isAscending)

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return tableViewData.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return tableViewData[section].rowDates.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    ...
    cell.rowDate = tableViewData[indexPath.section].rowDates[indexPath.row]
    ...
}
```

How would I order the section.rowDate , and when would I do it?

It doesn't look like I can do it as part of the section.sorted(byKeyPath) query... would I do it on initialisation of the SectionDate object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't sort the `rowDates` member on creation of the `SectionDate` object. The `List` is a Realm type that does not (necessarily) store the list in a sorted way.

You will need to sort the `rowDates` objects on each query of the object. One suggestion would be to add a computed property to the `SectionDate` class (computed - not stored) that returned a query sorted as required. Then access that property in the `cellForRowAt` function. E.g.:

```
extension SectionDates
{
  var sortedRowDates
  {
    return rowDates.sorted(byKeyPath: "date", ascending: isAscending)
  }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  ...
  cell.rowDate = tableViewData[indexPath.section].sortedRowDates[indexPath.row]
  ...
}
```

This of course means that the query is being run for each cell, but that's ok. There are other solutions, such as making a static copy of the data in viewDidLoad, but I don't think there's a need for that unless you run into any particular problems.